# Prove that the following expression is less than 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $p_{1},p_{2}$ are real numbers such that $ 1 \geq p_{1} > p_{2} \geq 0$

Prove that $(\frac{p_{1}+p_{2}}{2p_{1}})^{p_{1}}(\frac{p_{1}+p_{2}}{2p_{2}})^{p_{2}} < 1$

This came up while I was trying to show that the uniform distribution has maximal entropy, but I'm not sure how to prove this. I think there might be some trick that I am not seeing perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to $\ln(\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}^{\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}})\le \frac{1}{2}(\ln(p_1^{p_1})+\ln(p_2^{p_2}))$. Can you prove that the function $\ln(x^x)=x\ln x$ is a convex function over $[0,1]$?

Comment: Very nice answer, @Mr.T !  You just unearthed the entropy function mentionned by the asker.